# Auth.currentAuthenticatedUser nested results

Tags: aws-amplify

I'm using `Auth.currentAuthenticatedUser` to retrieve the details of a logged in user. The results that come back are difficult to interpret. The actual user details are nested under a key named `_55`. Is that expected? Will the name of that key ever change? I am leary of hardcoding this seemingly random key into my app just to extract current user data.

I'm seeing similar results with `currentUserInfo` and `currentUserPoolUserInfo`.

Answer (score 0):

That does seem strange, for me these methods return JSON with clear keys. Auth.currentAutheticatedUser() gives me [image: Auth.currentAuthenticatedUser response]
Maybe there is problems with your user cognito user / identity pool configurations.